# Seurat heatmap for two conditions

Tags: scrnaseq, seurat, differential-expression, 10x-genomics, heatmap

I have a Seurat object of four cancers and four controls

```
> colnames(pbmc@meta.data)
 [1] "orig.ident"       "nCount_RNA"       "nFeature_RNA"     "samples"         
 [5] "Condition"        "Gender"           "percent.mt"       "nCount_SCT"      
 [9] "nFeature_SCT"     "SCT_snn_res.0.75" "seurat_clusters"  "SCT_snn_res.0.5" 
> unique(pbmc@meta.data$Condition)
[1] "control" "cancer" 
>
```

[image]

I want to have a heat map of differentially expressed between cancers and controls like `figure 3A` in this paper

https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fgene.2020.610682/full

[image]

Do you have any idea please how I can do that? I've looked at the [integration tutorial](https://satijalab.org/seurat/articles/integration_introduction.html), but can't find the heatmap in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the `DoHeatmap` function in Seurat, which seems to be what that paper has used:

https://satijalab.org/seurat/articles/pbmc3k_tutorial.html#cb50

```
> DoHeatmap(pbmc, features = myGeneList, group.by="Condition")
```